# Check if 20% players of a tournament has played 8 or more rounds in previous year - Query Optimization - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization

So I have a table "tournaments" with the following attributes/columns:

- player_name
- tournament_name
- round_1, round_2, ......, round_10
- round_1_date, round_2_date, ......, round_10_date
- **Other columns**

I'm willing to check if **20%** players of a particular tournament has played **8 or more rounds** in **previous year**. If a person has played a round then there will be some score in that round else "**null**".

e.g: If a player has played round 1 and 2 then columns of round_1 and round_2 will be populated with some score along with round_1_date and round_2_date. All the other columns of rounds will be having **null**.
(Starting date can be round_1_date.)

I have made the following query which is giving **accurate results** but I beleive there can be a more **better/optimized** approach which will take less time than this one as this query will **run multiple times in a SQL loop for large dataset**. Query returns true or false.

```
SELECT
  (CAST((total_players_meeting_threshold_criteria/COUNT(t4.player_name)*100>=20) AS string)) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) total_players_meeting_threshold_criteria,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      (player_name),
      COUNT(round_1)+COUNT(round_2)+COUNT(round_3)+COUNT(round_4)+COUNT(round_5)+COUNT(round_6)+COUNT(round_7)+COUNT(round_8)+COUNT(round_9)+COUNT(round_10) AS total_rounds_played,
    FROM
      `Golf_DB_Women_Dataset.tournaments` t2
    WHERE
      player_name IN (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT player_name,
      FROM
        `tournaments` t1
      WHERE
        tournament_name = 'Tournament of Champions')
      AND t2.round_1_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB((
        SELECT
          round_1_date
        FROM
          `tournaments`
        WHERE
          tournament_name = 'Tournament of Champions'
        LIMIT
          1), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
      AND DATE_SUB((
        SELECT
          round_1_date
        FROM
          `tournaments`
        WHERE
          tournament_name = 'Tournament of Champions'
        LIMIT
          1), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY
      player_name
    HAVING
      total_rounds_played >= 8
    ORDER BY
      player_name) ) AS threshold_result,
  `tournaments` t4
WHERE
  t4.tournament_name = 'Tournament of Champions'
GROUP BY
  total_players_meeting_threshold_criteria
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing repeating data in parallel columns is just a lousy way to store data.  It should really be in separate rows in a table.  Sample data and desired results would also make the question clearer.  How is "previous year" determined, for instance?

Comment: Hi Gordon,

"Repeating data in parallel columns", I don't think it is happening in this case as each column stores different data.
Here's an image showing some sample data: https://res.cloudinary.com/abdurrehman/image/upload/v1615378457/samples/temp_xjnief.png
(I know the design is not so good but there are other reasons, let me know if the design is very poor)
Desired results is just true/false.

Comment: "How is previous year determined": We have a tournament whose round_1_date (starting date) is "10/03/2021" then I'd like to know whether 20% players of this tournament has played 8 or more rounds (in total) from "10/03/2020" to "10/03/2021"